# How important is the optimal connection count of eight connections per Amazon DocumentDB instance vCPU?

Tags: aws-documentdb

In AWS DocumentDB [migration guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/docdb-migration.html#docdb-migration-planning) there is a recommendation that states

*"The minimum optimal connection count is eight connections per Amazon DocumentDB instance vCPU. Although the Amazon DocumentDB instance connection limit is much higher, performance benefits of additional connections decline above eight connections per vCPU."*

What is this recommendation based upon and how important is it to follow in production deployments? Considering thousands of active connections my current MongoDB cluster is easily handling at any given moment, mapping that onto DocumentDB using 8/CPU recommendation results in hundreds of cores when sizing the cluster vs dozen cores on MongoDB.

---